# Copying an IIS log file based on file name, this is today's date

Tags: logging, dynamic, filenames, copying

I am trying to setup a batch script that will copy over the latest IIS logs based on the file name from our Exchange Client Access Server over to my system so that I can analyze the logs.  The problem is the file name's are based on the date, such as:

- u_ex130415.log
- u_ex130416.log
- u_ex130417.log
- u_ex130418.log
- u_ex130419.log
- u_ex130420.log

I was copying over the logs by the most recent log,

```
@echo off
pushd "Z:\W3SVC1\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.log /b /od') do set "logfile=%%a"
copy /b "%logfile%" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\Logs\cas1.log"
popd
```

but I was always getting the wrong file because of the way the logs get written.  Such as:

http://i292.photobucket.com/albums/mm19/dragonkinggaav/logs.jpg

So I need a script that will get the current date from my system's clock then use that date to copy over logs from the current day.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it to work by the most recent file.  I just changed the time that the copying starts.